# Unable to load SharePoint 2013 newsfeed

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, newsfeed

Our company's farm is facing newsfeed issue on SharePoint 2013, with latest CU installed ( August 2018 up until now)

Symptom:

- Everyone tab is unable to load. Error message

> The operation failed because the server could not access the
>   distributed cache. Internal type name:
>   Microsoft.Office.Server.Microfeed.MicrofeedException. Internal error
>   code: 55.

What I found in log:

SPMicrofeedThreadCollection.PopulateConsolidated  Exception:[Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfileException: Unexpected exception in FeedCacheService.GetPublishedFeed: **Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.  Parameter name: beginUtcDateTime**. ---> System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1[Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.FeedCacheFault]: Unexpected exception in FeedCacheService.GetPublishedFeed: Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.  Parameter name: beginUtcDateTime.    Server stack trace:      at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.HandleReply(ProxyOperationRuntime operation, ProxyRpc& rpc)     at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs...

I tried to search for this specific message but didn't find any result on Google.

I am very appreciate if anyone has experience on this can support me to resolve

--
Update: I have verified service account and app pool accounts. Both of them are already granted Full permission in User Profile Application

Comment: Try to retrieves the status of the cache like Waqas Sarwar suggested. Also check if all caches are available inside the cache service.

Comment: cache cluster health is 10 for all components

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Distributed cache is not in stable condition, as many thing depend on DC and NewsFeed is one of them.

In your farm, please run the below mentioned Script and check the status of the DC and make sure it is in healthy state.

```
Use-CacheCluster
Get-CacheHost
```

[THE OPERATION FAILED BECAUSE THE SERVER COULD NOT ACCESS THE DISTRIBUTED CACHE, SHAREPOINT 2013](https://dayansameera.wordpress.com/2013/09/03/the-operation-failed-because-the-server-could-not-access-the-distributed-cache-sharepoint-2013/)
As you mentioned, you confirm that UPA and farm admin has the Full permission within UPA, could you please check if both accounts get the permission on UPA databases as well?

Comment: Cache host is still up. I checked database permission and see both app pool and service account are granted SPDataAccess. UPA permissions have full control for Farm account, Farm admin, app pool, service acc, crawl acc